# Compress a very large number (in Python)

Tags: python, numbers, compression

I need a very very very large number (143 millions digits) to be compressed. I'm looking for a solution that compresses it without loss to at least 10% of it. I've tried zlib, zipfile, gzip, and so on, but none of those will really compress this number. So this is an idea I had, but the problem is that I don't know how to implement it

First, I have the number.

> 234512

Then I must split it in blocks of numbers that are smaller than 256.

> 234,51,2

I could split it if the size was fixed (eg, always 3 digits) but it may have 1,2 or 3 digits per block, so I got stuck here.

And after I get blocks of numbers smaller than 256, I will turn them into chars and write to the file.

EDIT: Since with that method I would lose landing zeros, I created an algorithm that compress ~50% of the number size:

1. As I have only 0-9 numbers as digits, I could say they're in hexadecimal (although they aren't) and convert to base 10, reducing its size. EDIT 2: skip this step. Actually, doing it will just increase its size!
2. I will get a smaller number with 0-9 numbers as digits, then I could again assume they're in hexadecimal. Thus, use unhexlify to turn it into a lot of bytes, which are half of the size! (if it's odd-length, add 'a' at the append to the number)

The code:

```
if len(o)%2: o+='a' #avoid odd-length
return unhexlify(o)
```

And the return data I can even compress with zlib. Total of 45% compression ratio.

Comment: If your number doesn't have any structure in it, you won't be able to compress it losslessly. I also doubt that we on stackoverflow come up in 5 minutes with a better algorithm as those used in the different well-known compression libraries.

Comment: “I've tried zlib, zipfile, gzip, and so on” So basically you have tried one algorithm and so on? You know that zlib, zipfile and gzip implement the same algorithm, right?

Comment: Your method compresses to 33%­­­—100%, do you want to go through with it?

Comment: What do you mean by structure? And I am not asking for an algorithm, just how to split it as I explained.

Comment: @NacibNeme: What is the number?

Comment: Without compression you can store that number in about 60 MB. Is this too much?

Comment: Do you want me post here a 143-million-digit number? Not a chance.

Comment: Yes, 60 MB is too much.

Comment: @Hyperboreus If the OP has his number in decimal and wants it in decimal at the end, converting to binary may be a tad expensive. But 9 decimal digits to the 32 bits can be implemented very cheap and wastes very little space.

Comment: With your compression idea, you store a 18 bit number (234512) as 24 bit (characters for 234,51,2) in a file. This isn't exactely compression but inflation.

Comment: With my idea I store a 6 bytes as only 3.

Comment: @NacibNeme: I don't care about the actual digits. How do you generate this number?

Comment: The integer 234512 has not 6 bytes (48 bit) bot only 18 bit. But nevermind.

Comment: @NacibNeme 60 MB is roughly (I haven't done the math but it seems right) the theoretical amount of information in “a number of 143 million digits”. You are not going to fit your number into a smaller space with the very sub-optimal method you describe, nor, in general, without finding the “structure” people are talking so much about.

Comment: What's the structure they talk about?

Comment: Structure means that the data (in your case your number) be sparse, or repetitive, or somehow else structured. Only if this is given a loss-less compression algorithm can work.

Comment: @NacibNeme: Is the number irrational? Does it have 140 million zeroes in the middle?

Comment: No, it is just an unsigned simple integer. I have don't it right now, but I am gonna put it on pastebin asap.

Comment: The maximum size a paste can be is 512 kilobytes. What do you *know* about this number, aside from its size?

Comment: It is very repetitive, with lots of consecutives 6 and 8.

Comment: Now then you can compress it. But I guess that the 6's and 8's are in its decimal representation. Hence you should compress its decimal representation and not the number itself.

Comment: @NacibNeme: Where does this number come from? It's most likely composite, so why don't you just factor it and store the factors?

Comment: if the number has many factors of 2, 3, 5 for example, being `x *  2^n2 * 3^n3 * 5^n5` just store the number of these factors... but if it does not any small factors at all, then one might want to forget the approach altogether...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

n = 313105074639950943116 #just an example

#your algorithm
chars = []
buff = ''
s = str (n)
while s:
    if int (buff + s [0] ) < 256:
        buff += s [0]
        s = s [1:]
    else:
        chars.append (int (buff) )
        buff = ''
if buff: chars.append (int (buff) )

print ('You need to write these numbers converted to chars: {}'.format (chars) )
print ('This are {} bytes of data.'.format (len (chars) ) )
print ('But you cannot decompress it, because you lose leading zeros.')

chars = []
while n:
    chars.append (n & 0xff)
    n = n >> 8

print ('Now if you just write the number to a file without your algorithm:')
print ('You need to write these numbers converted to chars: {}'.format (chars) )
print ('This are {} bytes of data.'.format (len (chars) ) )
print ('And you can actually read it again.')
```

**EDIT**: If the decimal representation of your number has a lot of sequences of 6s and 8s, you should try to use a RLE of the decimal representation, maybe combined with a Huffman tree.

**EDIT 2**: Considering (a) long runs of 6s and 8s, and (b) the fact you don't want to use some established algorithm, you can use some very crude RLE like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

n = 313666666666666688888888888888888866666666666666666666666666666610507466666666666666666666666666399509431888888888888888888888888888888888888888888881666666666666

s = str (n)
print (s)
comp = ''
count = None
while s:
    if s [0] in '01234579':
        if count:
            comp += ('<{}>' if count [0] == 6 else '[{}]').format (count [1] )
            count = None
        comp += s [0]
    if s [0] == '6':
        if count and count [0] == 6: count = (6, count [1] + 1)
        elif count:
            comp += ('[{}]').format (count [1] )
            count = (6, 1)
        else: count = (6, 1)
    if s [0] == '8':
        if count and count [0] == 8: count = (8, count [1] + 1)
        elif count:
            comp += ('<{}>').format (count [1] )
            count = (8, 1)
        else: count = (8, 1)
    s = s [1:]

if count: comp += ('<{}>' if count [0] == 6 else '[{}]').format (count [1] )

print (comp)
```

Comment: "RLE of the decimal representation, maybe combined with a Huffman tree" — which brings us back to DEFLATE.

Comment: @PavelAnossov: My point exactely. We won't cough up in five minutes a better algorithm than the established ones.